# Global variables not changing from one module to another

Tags: python, list, module, global-variables

Forgive me if this question has been asked, but I can't seem to find it.

I've been trying to (re)create a game that involves two teams. I represent them using lists of the names of the players.

The problem that I'm facing is that from a module to another I don't keep my global variables.

This is the tree of my project :

```
Project_Folder
  -- game.py
  -- functions.py
  -- variables.py
```

Inside the variables.py there is this :

```
player_list = []
team_1 = []
team_2 = []
```

And inside my functions.py :

```
import random
from variables import *
def init_teams():

    global player_list
    global team_1
    global team_2

    player_list = ["Player1", "Player2", "Player3", "Player4", "Player5"]
    # stuff above is normaly done with inputs and loops, but i symplified it

    for i in range(2):
        team_2.append(player_list.pop(
            random.randrange(len(player_list))))

    team_1 = player_list.copy()
    player_list += team_2

    print(team_1)
```

And finally in the main.py :

```
from functions import *
init_players()
print("Team 1 : {}, Team 2 : {}, Players : {}".format(
    team_1, team_2, player_list))
```

When I print the `team_1` variable inside the function, I get the normal result but when I do it in the main.py I get an empty list. Same with the `player_list` variable.

I've checked it with breakpoints using VS Code and seen that the `team_1` is actually changing (from the normal list to an empty list) from the function to the main file, but I have no idea why it does that.

If you have an idea, please tell me what I missed, it would save me a lot of searching!

Comment: Using `global` you redeclare this variables in current module scope. Just delete this 3 lines.

Comment: Sounds like you don't understand the use of the **`global`** keyword.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python) for a good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `global` keyword is working only in the used file. It can not be used to make value globally from another file.